# Быстрый поиск ответа и быстрый ответ на вопрос

Tags: поиск

1) Есть ли какой-нибудь мануал по быстрому поиску в интернете ответа касательно программирования? Понятно, что я  самостоятельно искать умею, но бывает что рыщешь/ищешь до потери сознания  и не можешь найти ответ. По неволе думаешь что ищешь как-то неправильно.

2) Вопрос связан с предыдущем...Скажите есть ли ресурс где я могу получить быстрый ответ по JS  в течении нескольких минут?  Пусть это даже глупый вопрос, но вот не знаю ответа и всё тут .. а надо двигаться дальше. Остается только спросить. Не хотелось бы конечно и быть забаненным из-за вопроса, на который уже 5 раз отвечали..

Comment: На данный вопрос сложно ответить однозначно. Поиск в интернете включён даже в некоторые программы информатики. Начинайте Ваш вопрос с языка программирования, а затем сам вопрос. Например: "JS как получить данные из формы". А что касается ресурса - то Вы всегда можете задать Ваш вопрос на данном комьюнити, никто Вас не забанит за глупые вопросы. Здесь всегда достаточно квалифицированных людей, чтобы ответить практически на любой вопрос. Так же можете пользоваться поиском на данном сайте. Здесь собрана большая база вопросов с ответами. Или можете воспользоваться англ. версией stackover.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, насчет "глупых вопросов" не все так просто. Тут много любителей минусовать "за не знание основ...". Как вы понимаете это весьма субъективно, так что нахватать минусов за вопросы очень легко. А вот постояно минусуемые вопросы приводят к бану

Comment: @avp В некотором роде Вы правы, но не все минусуют "глупые вопросы". Все допускают ошибки и у всех есть вопросы, которые могут показаться глупыми. Если человек искренне пытался найти ответ на вопрос, но ничего не вышло - ему обязательно же помогут.  Особенно, если следовать описанию "как задать хороший вопрос" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Другое дело, что многие и не пытаются искать элементарные вопросы в интернете. (Это те вопросы, на которые поисковик сразу же выдаёт с любого вопроса множество примеров) например "как создать функцию в js". Вот их и минусуют )

Comment: @Denis640Kb, если бы **все** минусовали то, что считают глупым, то тут бы и половины участноков не осталось. Достаточно буквально десятка. Впрочем, это тема не для основного сайта, а для Меты или чата "Генерал Дис Куссий" и посвещена она должна быть сути -- *БазаЗнаний vs ПомощьВсякому*

Comment: Отлично, я не могу задать вопрос  уже... Мне сказали что комьюнити не интересны вопросы и мне надо передохнуть и зайти позже.